# Changing form input type using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi
I am trying to change the type of `<input>` from `submit` to image using jquery so that the image is displayed during the AJAX request instead of the button. I am doing:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){$("#submit_btn").removeAttr("type").attr("image");});
```

and my HTML is:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" src="images/sending.gif" />
```

Am I doing it the right away? And if so, what's wrong because this ain't working :p

Comment: I solved it by using `.hide()` and `.show()` so: `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){$("#submit_btn").hide();
 $("#sending").show();
 });`
Now on `.ajaxStart` event the button hides and the image shows- with proper CSS positioning it gives the illusion of being replaced with an image. So it works- but not sure if it's the best way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){$("#submit_btn").attr("type","image");});
```

Using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the attribute, rather than removing it.

Answer (score 0):

May be this work for you:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){$("#submit_btn")..attr(type : 'image');});
```